# stop playing sound when lock the mobile

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

> hi is there is any code that stop play sound when i lock the mobile .As I had created **Android** app which play sound in specific time and i want user to **mute** the sound when press at **lock** button .

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen for screen off intent

```
android.intent.action.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF
```

Ok. Look into documentation http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html for more detailed info about intent handling. Here is one of methods:

@Override
    protected void onResume() {

```
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);


    registerReceiver(new IntentListener(), intentFilter);

    super.onResume();
}
```

And inner class defining IntentListener

```
private class IntentListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      //here code do be executed on when intent comes
    }
}
```

Also remember to unregister receiver in onPause():

```
unregisterReceiver(intentListener);
```

I haven't checked this code, so please do it yourself

Comment: I searched about it but i couldnot , i am sorry i am beginner so if y explain more i will be very happy

Comment: i had this error  android.intent cannot be resolved to a variable